# Full-Screen Auto-Location Change in OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, spaces, desktop, mission-control

I'm using a MacBook Pro with Retina, currently at OS X 10.10.3.
I use it for both personal and work related matters, more often than not, at the same time. As such, I have 6 desktops ready to go at any given time.

I have the "Auto-Arrange" option switched off, so I don't lose my mind going through the desktops.

My problem lies in switching an app into full screen. The default behavior of course is for the space to go to the far right of all the desktops, and in cases where I'm only using 2 or 3 desktops, I end up having to swipe into mission control and either manually rearranging for every app I switch into full-screen, or when I'm in "auto-mode", I just end up swiping 4 times or so to get to the space...

Any behavior can be changed, just a matter of finding a way.
Anyone know how to change it so that full-screen apps show up on the left of the other desktops/spaces (same as where the dashboard is), instead of being added to the right of them?

Answer (score 1):

I've never found any way to get full-screen apps to go to the left. At least they don't drop randomly in the middle of other Desktops like they used to, so at least you now know where they're going to be.

My workaround has been to use the default ctrl/number key commands in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control, as below, which in my case makes the first full-screen app accessible by  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>6</kbd>  then  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>  or one swipe.

[image]